# Why are my menu items below the actual menu bar (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a very plain and simple menu in CSS. Currently I have the html code:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}

#header{
        position:fixed;
        height: 20px;
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index:9;
        text-align:center;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    }

    #header{
        top:0px;
    }
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhoeaubz/) with my code, you can see that items are below actual dark bar - how can I change that? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that `div#header`, if the `ul#navlist` is already a block element? In fact, if you remove the div from your markup, and replace in your CSS the selector `#header{` by `#navlist {`, you will have your problem solved. But, if you need to keep that div, then - as others said - remove the `ul` margin.

Answer (score 5):

Because `ul` element has default `margin`. You can remove it:

```css
#navlist li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}
#header {
  top: 0px;
}
#navlist {
  margin: 0;/*set margin to 0 to ul element*/
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item four</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item five</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**References**

[**typical default display properties for ul element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me one last thing - how to spread a little bit more the space between each menu position? Which parameter is responsible for that?

Comment: You mean something like that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aud9g20h/)? You can add `padding: padding: 0 25px 0 25px;` to `#navlist li`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the margin of the ul:

```
#navlist {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you are posting exactly the same answer with someone else some time after?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was testing the code, I posted the answer and then I saw yours. Sometimes it happends, don't you think so?

Comment: Alex - It's not a difficult answer to this question. We would all come to the same solution of course.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `ul` tag (`#navlist`) has a `margin` on it by default, set by the browsers default stylesheet. Your bar also has a fixed height and this has the effect of pushing it down.

See a fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/6mk4kLj8/

I removed the `margin` from `#navlist` and removed the `height` from `#header`, to make it more flexible.

**CSS**

```
#navlist {

    margin: 0;

}

#navlist li {

    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;

}

#header {

    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index:9;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 0;

}
```